# How to get input file size as column in AWS Athena external tables

Tags: amazon-athena

I know how to get the path of the files via pseudo column like, for example:

```sql
select "$path" from table
```

But I also want to bring the filesize next to it, is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see there is development done here in Presto but somehow it does not work in Athena.
https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/1428

Comment: Have you tried querying S3 inventory https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html ?

Comment: Thanks for your response but how will this help to use in Athena?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use attributes on the source files like file size and file modified time:

```
SELECT "$path", "$file_size", "$file_modified_time"
FROM my_table
LIMIT 10
```